# Android Studio 1.2, running test

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to follow the Android course done by the Google team (with Udacity, https://www.udacity.com/course/developing-android-apps--ud853)

However, I am not able to get the tests to run properly.

With Android Studio 1.2, I am seeing "Test events were not received" instead of seeing the list of all the passing and failing test.

How do I go about with getting tests running properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run it from single class...not from the whole package, and chose AndroidTest option...it helped me...so give it a try